# Compile SQLCipher on Mac OS 10.8 (64 bit)

Tags: macos, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit, sqlcipher

When I compile SQLCIPHER on MacOS 64bit

```
./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2" LDFLAGS="/Users/administrator/Documents/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a"
```

I get 32bit lib libsqlite3.a 
But I need a 64bit libsqlite3.a

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified you are linking against a 64-bit version of `libcrypto.a` since it appears you are building OpenSSL yourself?  You will want to run `./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc` if you are building OpenSSL from source for x86_64.  The version of OpenSSL found on the system should contain both i386 and x86_64 versions of the architecture, so you shouldn't need to rebuild OpenSSL.  Could you run `file .libs/sqlite` and show the output following a compilation?

Answer (score 8):

The new version of SQLCIPHER does not require OpenSSL anymore.

You first need to configure the build, these are the suggested settings for CommonCrypto rather than SSL as a crypto provider.

```
./configure --enable-load-extension --enable-tempstore=yes \
--with-crypto-lib=commoncrypto \
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3" \ LDFLAGS="/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/Current/Security"
```

Then you need to make it:

```
make
```

You will get a 64 bit statically linked SQLLite library.